# Calculating the residue of the function $f(z)=\frac{\mathrm{e}^z}{z^2}$ in the point $z=0$ straight from the definition.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I am trying to calculate the residue of the function $f(z) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^z}{z^2}$ in the point $z=0$, straight from the definition.

From the residual formula, we know that the answer has to be:
$$
\underset{z=0}{\textrm{Res}} \,\frac{\mathrm{i}^z}{z^2}=(\mathrm{e}^z)'(0)=\mathrm{i}^0 = 1. 
$$
The definition of the residue in the point $a$ is:
$$
\underset{z=a}{\textrm{Res}}\,f(z)=\frac1{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\int_{C(a,\epsilon)^+}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z. 
$$
I use $\epsilon=1$, Therefore, I need to calculate the following integral by hand:
$$
\int_{C(0,1)^+}\frac{\mathrm{e}^z}{z^2}\,\mathrm{d}z. 
$$
That's where I am stuck. Can we use a complex anti-deriviative perhaps? I now tried to parameterize it using $\gamma:t\mapsto \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t}$, for $t\in(0,2\pi)$. This then gives by definition the integral
$$
\int_{C(0,1)^+} \frac{\mathrm{e}^z}{z^2}\,\mathrm{d}z=\int_0^{2\pi} f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t}}}{\mathrm{e}^{2\mathrm{i}t}}\mathrm{ie}^{\mathrm{i}t}\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{ie}^{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t}}}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t}}\,\mathrm{d}t. 
$$
I don't know how to integrate this.

Comment: I find it strange to see that the Residue Theorem is used to define the residue at  a point. Which book are you following?

Comment: Where is this used to define the residue at a point? I'm using a local syllabus written by my teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your definition, but my definition says that the residus it the 1st coefficient of the singular part. Since $$e^z=1+z+o(z),$$ you get $$\frac{e^z}{z^2}=\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z}+o(1).$$
And so, the residue arise naturally.

Comment: I have a different definition then, apparently, but nice suggestion! And apart from the definition of the residue, is it possible to calculate the integral $\int \frac{e^z}{z^2} dz$ `by hand'?

Comment: Of course. Check [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).

Comment: I mean, without using the Residue theorem?

Comment: You can use Cauchy formula... but the idea is the same. You can also reprove Cauchy formula to compute your integral... But the idea of such integral is always residue theorem.